# How to create a data table that consists of a subset of columns of an original table in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python. My data table (Table1) has 21 columns and thousands of rows. It is so huge I cannot open it on my laptop. It looks somewhat like this:

ABCDEFG, HIJKLMNO, PQRSTUVW, TEYHDSJD  ........

TRGFHFJ, GDGSANTO, JDKNVWWR, URNWHJX  ........

.......

However, I need to reproduce a subset of this table that only consists of columns 10-21. I have tried the following:

```
import sys
import csv

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as input:
   readinput = csv.reader(input, delimiter=',')
   with open("output.csv", 'wt') as output:
      writer=csv.writer(output, delimiter="\t")
      for row in input:
         values =  [row[10],row[11],row[12],row[13],row[14],row[15],row[16],row[17],row[18],row[19],row[20],row[21]]
         writer.writerow([values])
         print (row[10])
```

But it turns out the cvs.reader's expression "row[10]" is not interpreting this as the 10th element of the row (=the 10th column). Instead, it gives me the 10th letter. So the output is not the 10th to 21st columns of Table1, but it is the 10th to 21st letters, somewhat like this:

K, L, M, N, O, "", P, Q, R, S, T, U

S, A, N, T, O, "", J, D, K, N, V, W

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should use `open(sys.argv[1], "r", newline='')` when passing the file to the `csv.reader`.  It matters only when the quoted value may contain newline sequence as the part of the data.  Anyway, it is better sometimes to get used to keeping it as the convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `for row in input`, I guess you wanted `for row in readinput`.

Comment: Oh my God, that was it! That's why it didn't work... Thank you so much. I was brooding over this for hours.

Comment: My +1.  This is one of the reasons why to accept the conventional name `reader = csv.reader(...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .csv file, and you want to create another .csv such that the latter file consist of only columns 10 through 21 of the former file, you can do this:

```
with open('old_file.csv') as old_f, open('new_file.csv', 'w') as new_f:
    for line in old_f:
        new_f.write(','.join(line.split(',')[10:]))
```

Comment: This won't work for lines such as "a,b",c - you have to parse it properly.

Comment: Yes, commas should only be acting as delimiters.